# react- Autocomplete/Textfield not rendering due to maximum update depth exceeded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

My textfield/autocomplete field is not rendering on my page. I have wrapped react-hook-form around it to help me control the form.

Here the error I get from my console:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at Controller
```

Here is my autocomplete form, I cant seem to find any help about this on other threads,

```
            <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => setData(data))}>
              <Controller
                render={({ onChange, ...props }) => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    className={classes.container}
                    id="stock_list"
                    name="stock_list"
                    multiple
                    options={inputOptions.companies}
                    filterOptions={filterOptions}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol}
                    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.symbol === value.symbol}
                    renderOption={(option) =>
                    {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <span style={{ fontWeight: 500, fontSize: "20px", paddingRight: "1rem" }}>{option.symbol}</span><span style={{ color: "#C6C6C6", fontSize: "24px" }}> | </span><span style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>{option.company}</span>
                        </>
                      )
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField 
                        {...params}
                        style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                        id="stock_list"
                        name="stock_list"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Companies"
                        className={classes.container}
                        component={TextField}
                        />
                       )}
                      />
                    )}
                    name="stock_list"
                    onChange={([event, data]) => {
                      return data;
                    }}
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue=""             
                />
            </form>
```

How did I structure my `<Controller>` `<Autocomplete>`  and or `<TextField>` wrong here?

edit: Here is how im getting my inputOptions

```
const [inputOptions, setInputOptions] = useState({ companies: [] });

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    Axios.get("https://app.stockbuckets.io/tickers/").then((res) =>
    {
      setInputOptions({ companies: res.data });
    });
  }, [setInputOptions]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the dependency array in your `useEffect` to `[inputOptions]` and not `[setInputOptions]`, that should help at least.

Comment: Thank you, that did help, I also removed `component={TextField}` which was not causing the original textfield to render properly.